# How to enable rails and postgresql on start up in centos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nginx, centos, ghost-blog

I have a server with centos running rails application each time when I reboot my system I have doing following tasks manually. How to enable all the following tasks in start up

To stop and start my nginx I am using

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp # to stop
sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx # to start
```

And to start my postgresql I am using following command

service postgresql-9.2 start/stop/restart

Once I connect my server using ssh and try some postgresql command ill get error as

```
postgresql-9.2: unrecognized service
```

To avoid this am using command

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH
```

And then ill use postgresql(Doing export command each time when I connect through ssh).

And I am using ghost blog facing same issue whenever I reboot my server I need to run following command to start my ghost blog

```
NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js
```

How to solve all these. Can any one help

Answer (score 2):

You can add the process in your init script that is at `/etc/init.d/`
.You can further read  [run script on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)